# Couldn't replace values in the list using dict conversion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below list of dictionaries -

```
result=[{'cat': '66', 'count': 5, 'ids': [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]},
        {'cat': '27', 'count': 4, 'ids': [20, 22, 23, 24]},
        {'cat': '29', 'count': 2, 'ids': [20, 24]},
        {'cat': '66 & 27', 'count': 4, 'ids': [20, 22, 23, 24]},
        {'cat': '66 & 27 & 29', 'count': 2, 'ids': [20, 24]}
        ]
```

Am trying to replace cat id with the values based on the dict (conversions), I tried below code

```
conversions ={'66':'Tesla','27':'Audi','29':'BMW'}
for do in result:
    do['cat']=conversions[do['cat']]

print(result)
```

This gives me Keyerror for the key '66 & 27', how can I get the result as 'Tesla & Audi'.  For the key '66 & 27 & 29' it should give 'Tesla & Audi & BMW'.

Am not sure how I can handle this scenario. Any suggestions with the approach for achieving this result ?

Comment: Add the key `'66 & 27'` to your conversions dict. I don't think you have defined clearly what should happen with that key

Comment: In the question, I used raw data.. but these values would come from the database table.. I cannot use '66 & 27' as key.. I need to somehow parse the string and replace 66 with 'Tesla' and 27 with 'Audi' ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split `do['cat']` by single space, process each element of the resulting list, and concatenate the result using single space as the separator.

```
for do in result:
    do['cat'] = ' '.join([conversions.get(x, x) for x in do['cat'].split(' ')])
```

`conversions.get(x, x)` returns `conversions[x]` if `x` is convertible and `x` otherwise.

For your data, this approach will produce

```
[{'cat': 'Tesla', 'count': 5, 'ids': [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]},
 {'cat': 'Audi', 'count': 4, 'ids': [20, 22, 23, 24]},
 {'cat': 'BMW', 'count': 2, 'ids': [20, 24]},
 {'cat': 'Tesla & Audi', 'count': 4, 'ids': [20, 22, 23, 24]},
 {'cat': 'Tesla & Audi & BMW', 'count': 2, 'ids': [20, 24]}]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for this.